# there is not any notification recieved from FCM

Tags: android, firebase-cloud-messaging

i'm using FCM and follow instructions on firebase site but notifications not working when app in background

i already sync gradle library and download json file and sync done but not notifications recieved when app in background

app gradle

```
dependencies {
    ///////
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.2'

          // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add

> classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.1'
>
> classpath'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.2'

in project gradle and google plugin in app gradle file.
Then add the following dependencies:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.2.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:19.0.0'
```

You need to create a service of FCM to recieve notifications.

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

    private NotificationManager notificationManager;
    private static final String ADMIN_CHANNEL_ID = "CHANNEL_ID";

    @Override
    public void onNewToken(String s) {
        super.onNewToken( s );
    }

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        super.onMessageReceived( remoteMessage );

        Map<String, String> data = remoteMessage.getData();
        String body = data.get("body");
        String title = data.get("title");
        String image = data.get("image");

        notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService( Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            setupChannels( title, body );
        }

        Log.d( "Notification", "onMessageReceived: "  + image);

        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, NotificationActivity.class);
        notificationIntent.setFlags( Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP );
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService( this, 0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT );
        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder( this, ADMIN_CHANNEL_ID )
                .setSmallIcon( R.drawable.ic_launcher_background )
                .setContentTitle( remoteMessage.getNotification( ).getTitle( ) )
                .setContentText( remoteMessage.getNotification( ).getBody( ) )
               .setContentIntent( pendingIntent );

        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService( Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE );

        notificationManager.notify( 0, notificationBuilder.build( ) );
    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    private void setupChannels(String adminChannelName, String adminChannelDescription) {
        NotificationChannel adminChannel;
        adminChannel = new NotificationChannel( ADMIN_CHANNEL_ID, adminChannelName, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_LOW );
        adminChannel.setDescription( adminChannelDescription );
        adminChannel.enableLights( true );
        adminChannel.setLightColor( Color.RED );
        adminChannel.enableVibration( true );
        if (notificationManager != null) {
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel( adminChannel );
        }
    }

}
```

And add this code to your manifest:

```
<service
        android:name=".MyFirebaseMessagingService"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several steps for achieving the notification when application is in background.

1. You need to use **POST** parameter in **Android FCM** service.
2. You need to code down the thing inside **onMessageReceived()** from FCM dependencies.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive#handling_messages

Comment: i tried solution i just found that i forget this gradle library       implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.0.0'      because i just send notification without message body

Comment: @EslamElassal If you think its worth then upvote the answer/accept it it will help other too.

Comment: i'm a new member on stack overflow , i just type answer but the site not accept the format , i will try now to answer with acceptable format

Answer (score 0):

because i just send notification without message body 
i tried solution i just found that i forget this gradle library

implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.0.0'